# Binding attached property to attached property inside a control template

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

**Here is a working example of my issue:** https://github.com/themimcompany/AttachedPropertyIssue

I have a `Style` for a `Button` that defines a `ControlTemplate`. Inside the `ControlTemplate` I have a `TextBlock` that has the same attached property. I want to set/bind the `TextBlock`'s attached property to the value of the `Button`'s attached property. The attached property is a simple `int` value.

How do I get this working? Is this possible to do in UWP? I get errors that don't give me indication on how to fix this. Like `Unspecified error`...

Here is my Style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock local:Translation.TranslationModelID="{Binding Path=(local:Translation.TranslationModelID),
                                                                                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is my attached property definition:

```
public class Translation
{
    public static int GetTranslationModelID(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(TranslationModelIDProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTranslationModelID(DependencyObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TranslationModelIDProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TranslationModelIDProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TranslationModelID", typeof(int), typeof(FrameworkElement), new PropertyMetadata(0));

}
```

Here is the button I'm trying to define, notice I want to assign the attached property of the button- then take the value in the ControlTemplate and assign it to the TextBlock's attached property (look at the style):

```
<Button local:Translation.TranslationModelID="1" />
```

**Explaining once more:** I have an attached property assigned to a `Button` and I would like to assign the value of that `Button`'s attached property to the same attached property of a `TextBlock`in the `ControlTemplate` of that `Button`'s `Style`. It's not working as I expect. I get `Unspecified error..` exception at run time. How do I get this working?

**Here is a working example of my issue:** https://github.com/themimcompany/AttachedPropertyIssue

**EDIT:**

This approach is giving me a different error. `The property 'TranslationModelID' was not found in type 'PassingAttachedPropertyInControlTemplater.Translation'. [Line: 17 Position: 40]`

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock local:Translation.TranslationModelID="{TemplateBinding local:Translation.TranslationModelID}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btn" local:Translation.TranslationModelID="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT can you be more detailed with your explanation. The property should exist because its a member of the Translation class- it's public and static. Why can't it find it?

Comment: I check official document, I think you could not use [`TemplateBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/templatebinding-markup-extension) to bind attached property.

Comment: Could you tell us what feature you want to realize?

Comment: I want to assign an attached property of the templated parent to an attached property of an element inside a ControlTemplate using TemplateBinding or regular Binding

Comment: I have replied your case please check the following.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to assign an attached property of the templated parent to an attached property of an element inside a ControlTemplate using TemplateBinding or regular Binding

For your requirement, you could create Templated Control that inherit button. Then set TextBlock Attached property in the code behind. Please check the follow segment code.

```
public sealed class CustomButton : Button, IDisposable
{
    private long token;
    private TextBlock Tbk;

    public CustomButton()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomButton);
    }

    private void CallBackMethod(DependencyObject sender, DependencyProperty dp)
    {
        UpdateAttachedPropertyValue();
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        token = this.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(AttachedPropertyTest.Translation.TranslationModelIDProperty, CallBackMethod);
        Tbk = GetTemplateChild("TBK") as TextBlock;
        UpdateAttachedPropertyValue();        
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.UnregisterPropertyChangedCallback(AttachedPropertyTest.Translation.TranslationModelIDProperty,token);
    }

    private void UpdateAttachedPropertyValue()
    {
        AttachedPropertyTest.Translation.SetTranslationModelID(Tbk, AttachedPropertyTest.Translation.GetTranslationModelID(this));
    }

}
```

**Xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomButton" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomButton">
                <Border
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TBK"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```